# Regex: Find ID in HTML element

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the `oID` parameter from this HTML source with a regex condition:

```
<img src="button_print.gif" style="cursor:hand" onclick="window.open('http://domain.com/print_order.php?oID=5', 'popup', 'toolbar=0, width=640, height=600')">
```

I´ve tried many different ways now but I´m unable to find the right way.
For my understanding this regex should work (but it doesn´t):

```
oID=(\d+)
```

Maybe somebody has a hint for me?

Comment: It works for me. [reFiddle example](http://refiddle.com/h4k)

Comment: [Don't try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2846923).

Comment: @RyanCarlson He isn't trying to parse HTML with regex. He's trying to retrieve a URL parameter

Comment: @BackSlash You're right, still I'd prefer extracting `onclick` value first.

Comment: You regex works for me: http://regex101.com/r/nR2lP8

Comment: ^ works just fine for me too.

Comment: @raina77ow Of course. But in my personal opinion, I think there is no need to use a HTML-parsing library just for one string

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a logical problem for me with regex_replace. This replace shoudl simply give me the ID:

$string = '<img src="button_print.gif" style="cursor:hand" onclick="window.open(\'http://domain.com/print_order.php?oID=5\', \'popup\', \'toolbar=0, width=640, height=600\')">';
var_dump(preg_replace('/oID=(\d+)/','Output: $1',$string));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the string before and after the match too:

```
.*?oID=(\d+).*
```

The command:

```
$string = '<img src="button_print.gif" style="cursor:hand" onclick="window.open(\'domain.com/print_order.php?oID=5\', \'popup\', \'toolbar=0, width=640, height=600\')">'; 
var_dump(preg_replace('/.*?oID=(\d+).*/','Output: $1',$string));
```

The result:

```
Output: 5
```

[Online test.](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Ak)